# How to get a counter for a guessing game

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, counter

I'm attempting to add a counter to my program to count the number of guesses that the user has taken. I'm not sure how to do this...

Below is my code:

```
import java.util.*;//imports the utilities
public class WordPyramid {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int n;
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Making 3 random numbers…"); 
            System.out.println("What is the sum?");
            Random rn =new Random();
            int answer = rn.nextInt(10) + 1;
            int answera=rn.nextInt(10) + 1;
            int answerb=rn.nextInt(10) + 1;;
            int fans =answer+answera+answerb;
            while ((n = kb.nextInt()) != fans) {

                  System.out.println("Sorry, try again");
                  System.out.println("What is the sum?");
                }
            System.out.println("");

          }



    }
```

Comment: `int counter = 0;` and `counter++` when they make a guess

Comment: I strongly recommend doing some Java tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider having a new `int count = 0` outside your `while` loop, and using an increment like `count++` inside your loop.

This will increase your value for `count` by 1 with each incorrect guess, or effectively each time the `while` loop is run through.

You may find  [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)  informative as well, along with the rest of the Java Tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show every try number , here is a simple example :

```
       int i=0;
        while ((n = kb.nextInt()) != fans) {
              i++;
              System.out.println("Try number : "+i);

              System.out.println("Sorry, try again");
              System.out.println("What is the sum?");

            }
```